File Upload in Spring Boot with ZK Framework
I am trying to implement file upload functionality in my Spring Boot application using the ZK Framework. I have created the necessary ZUL file and Java controllers, but the file upload feature is not working as expected.
Here is what I have done so far :
@Command
@NotifyChange("fileName")
public void handleFileUpload(@BindingParam("event") UploadEvent event) {
    if (event.getMedias() != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("You uploaded: \n");

        for (Media m : event.getMedias()) {
            String filename = m.getName().toLowerCase();
            sb.append(filename);
            sb.append(" (");
            sb.append(m.getContentType());
            sb.append(")\n");

            // Debug: Show filename being processed
            Clients.showNotification("Processing file: " + filename, "info", null, "middle_center", 3000);

            if (!filename.endsWith(".txt") && !filename.endsWith(".xls") && !filename.endsWith(".csv")) {
                Clients.showNotification("Invalid file type: " + filename, "error", null, "middle_center", 3000);
                return; // Exit on invalid file type
            }

            try {
                Path uploadPath = Paths.get("uploads");
                if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
                    Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
                }
                Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(m.getName());
                Files.copy(m.getStreamData(), filePath);
                fileName = m.getName(); // Update the fileName property

                // Debug: Show file path
                Clients.showNotification("File saved to: " + filePath.toString(), "info", null, "middle_center", 3000);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Clients.showNotification("Error uploading file: " + ex.getMessage(), "error", null, "middle_center", 3000);
            }
        }

        // Show uploaded files
        Clients.showNotification(sb.toString(), "info", null, "middle_center", 3000);
    } else {
        Clients.showNotification("You uploaded no files!", "warning", null, "middle_center", 3000);
    }
} 


<button id="btn" iconSclass="fa fa-upload" sclass="btn btn-primary"
        label="Upload File" upload="true" 
        onUpload="@command('handleFileUpload', event=event)"/>

<textbox id="fileNameTextbox" value="@bind(vm.fileName)"
         sclass="form-control col-sm-5" placeholder="File Name"
         readonly="true"/>


What is the current issue? Is the command invoked, but encounter an issue, or does the command not fire at all? Additionally, which ZK version and spring-boot version are you running? Lastly, can you show how you are attaching the Java class to the zul? From the syntax used, it should be a viewModel="..." attribute (MVVM), not an apply="..." attribute (MVC)
